# Controlar entradas e saídas extras no Arduino Uno por software

Tags: arduino

Estou desenvolvendo um projeto utilizando o Arduino, mas preciso de mais terminais (entradas e saídas) analógicos do que os dispostos na placa.

É possível controlar, via software, mais terminais analógicos sem a necessidade de soldar algo na placa, usar shields, ou componentes externos?

Comment: Aqui as perguntas são sobre [desenvolvimento de software](/help) apenas (a própria tag arduino explica isso na descrição, basta fazer hover com o ponteiro do mouse, ou clicar nela), mas a rede tem um site específio para [arduino.se] e microcontroladores, provavelmente já encontrará resposta lá. Mas mesmo com a postagem fechada, dicas ainda podem ser dadas via comentários.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Olá tudo bem? Para esta situação pode ser pensado no seguinte:

Multiplexação (Multiplexers): Você pode usar circuitos multiplexadores para expandir o número de entradas analógicas. Um multiplexador permite que você conecte vários sensores a um único pino analógico e, através do software, selecione qual sensor deseja ler a qualquer momento.

Comunicação Serial (I2C, SPI, etc.): Você pode usar dispositivos externos que se comunicam com o Arduino através de protocolos como I2C ou SPI para adicionar entradas analógicas. Por exemplo, há chips ADC (Analog-to-Digital Converter) que podem ser controlados via I2C.

Arduinos adicionais: Em alguns casos, você pode considerar a adição de outro Arduino ao seu projeto para lidar com mais entradas analógicas e, em seguida, comunicar-se com o Arduino principal para relatar os valores medidos.

Redirecionamento de Função (bit-banging): Em algumas situações específicas, é possível utilizar a técnica de bit-banging, que envolve manipular diretamente os níveis de tensão de pinos digitais para simular a funcionalidade de um pino analógico. No entanto, isso pode ser complicado e pode não ser adequado para todos os casos.

Comment: Sobre a resposta, é legal a iniciativa em querer ajudar, mas como o site não é sobre hardware, caberia melhor no campo de comentários. Aproveitando, consegue me explicar sucintamente aqui nos comentários que relação teria bit banging com uma leitura analógica num pino digital? Nem precisa detalhar muito não, só fiquei curioso pra entender que relação uma coisa tem com outra, qual seria o princípio que você usaria num cenário desses.

Comment: Justamente para manipular diretamente os níveis de bits do que usar hardware dedicado.

Comment: Poderia esclarecer em termos práticos como seria possível isso? Numa lida por cima não está fazendo muito sentido (nem falo por mal, é que ficou parecendo aquelas coisas de ChatGPT sem pé nem cabeça). Se puder comentar um exemplo prático (ou comentar algo do ponto de vista de eletrônica que sustente essa idéia) talvez ajude, posso estar equivocado ou não ter entendido algum detalhe. A parte dos multiplexadores e I2C até está bem clara e concordo (até acredito que algo como um ADS1115 ou 74HC4067 serviria, se a autora aceitasse devices externos). Só estranhei a parte de bit banging;